# Gnome causes system hang; Unity does not. How to locate problem?

Tags: gnome, bug-reporting, 16.04

There's a bug in Gnome Shell, or possibly something beneath it (seems to apply to gdm, too) that causes a complete system lock up when I plug in an external monitor.

This does not happen when using Unity.

There aren't any logs because the system just locks up and has a blank screen. You can't get out with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, nor with the special <kbd>SysRq</kbd> triggers.

That's the simple version of the diagnostic. The more complex bit is like:

```
monitor  driver  de         result
-------- ------- ---------- -----------------------
internal intel   gnome      works
internal intel   unity      works
internal nvidia  gnome      works
internal nvidia  unity      works
external intel   gnome      massive crash
external intel   unity      Kernel buffer underrun
external nvidia  gnome      massive crash
external nvidia  unity      works
```

The buffer underrun I've [reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1568865) against the kernel - the system was alive after, so I had the logs etc. But I'm not sure how to report the gnome problem.

### edit

This got down voted because it sounded like the generic "how to report a bug". I suppose what I'm asking instead is: does anyone know of a library used by gnome and gdm that is not used by unity or lightdm, and that might be key to understanding where the fault lies? I was surprised that gdm fails, for example, and that led me to thing it's not a gnome shell issue...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I report a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: I hadn't meant it to be a duplicate of that. I've edited my q.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/FindRightPackage) I should report the bug under:

- the failing display manager: gdm3
- xorg because gnome-shell will not start